# is `foo<Type1, Types...>` legal when foo is a struct which accepts single template parameter?

Tags: c++, templates, clang, libstdc++, compiler-bug

When playing with libstdcxx's [`test_property`](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/testsuite/util/testsuite_tr1.h#L66):

```
template<template<typename...> class Property,
       typename Type1, typename... Types>
constexpr bool
test_property(typename Property<Type1, Types...>::value_type value)
{
    return (Property<Type1, Types...>::value == value
      && Property<Type1, Types...>::type::value == value);
 }
```

`class Property` accepts at least 1 template parameter(`Type1`).

[Here](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/testsuite/20_util/is_copy_assignable/value.cc#L70) is a use case:

```
static_assert(test_property<is_copy_assignable, ExceptMoveAssignClass>(false), "");
```

But I found clang doesn't work fine with this function:

```
prog.cc:29:3: error: no matching function for call to 'test_property'
                test_property<std::is_copy_assignable, DeletedMoveAssignClass>(false);
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
prog.cc:12:1: note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure [with Property = std::is_copy_assignable, Type1 = DeletedMoveAssignClass]: too many template arguments for class template 'is_copy_assignable'
test_property(typename Property<Type1, Types...>::value_type value)
^                      ~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

The root cause is clang doesn't allow `class Property` to be class that only accepts one template parameter like `template< class T > struct is_copy_assignable;`. Once `class Property` is modified into `Property<Type1>`, it will compile successfully:

```
template<template<typename...> class Property, typename Type1>
constexpr bool
ya_test_property(typename Property<Type1>::value_type value)
{
    return (Property<Type1>::value == value
        && Property<Type1>::type::value == value);
}
```

here is demo https://wandbox.org/permlink/LlL1o57Yted5WZo5

Of course, this function is from libstdcxx, [so gcc can pass compile](https://wandbox.org/permlink/bMbGAuw2jYdXbczw). Is this clang's bug?

Comment: Why do you use an extra template type parameter `Type1` instead of [using the only template type parameter pack `Types...`](https://wandbox.org/permlink/igLQKIPwhmnyiMGS)?

Comment: @Constructor the `an extra template type` is just for explain the reason, not other workarounds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a Clang bug if I'm interpreting [[temp.variadic]/7](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.variadic#7) correctly:

> When N is zero, the instantiation of the expansion produces an empty
>   list. Such an instantiation does not alter the syntactic
>   interpretation of the enclosing construct, even in cases where
>   omitting the list entirely would otherwise be ill-formed or would
>   result in an ambiguity in the grammar. [ *Example*:
>
> ```
> template<class... T> struct X : T... { };
> template<class... T> void f(T... values) {
>   X<T...> x(values...);
> }
>
> template void f<>();    // OK: X<> has no base classes
>                         // x is a variable of type X<> that is value-initialized
> ```
>
> — end example ]

Similarly, while `std::is_copy_assignable<ExceptMoveAssignClass , >` is ill-formed, an empty pack should not put us in this state. It should be equivalent to `std::is_copy_assignable<ExceptMoveAssignClass>`, which is well-formed.

Of course, if the pack *wasn't* empty, then we'd be passing too many arguments, which *is* ill-formed. But that is not the case.

Comment: Is not it the concequence that Clang has not yet fully implemented C++17 template template argument/parameter matching? http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0522r0.html

Comment: @Oliv - Good question. I am... unsure.

Comment: The [Clang status page](https://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html#cxx2a) says about P0522:

(10): Despite being the resolution to a Defect Report, this feature is disabled by default in all language versions, and can be enabled explicitly with the flag `-frelaxed-template-template-args` in Clang 4 onwards. The change to the standard lacks a corresponding change for template partial ordering, resulting in ambiguity errors for reasonable and previously-valid code. This issue is expected to be rectified soon.